# Folder of standardstyle.xml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Hi there I'am quite new to c# and WPF and was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem that I am currently having.

I switched to Visual Studio 2013 to programming Windows 8.1 app with c# and i would like to know where is standardstyle.xml that in VS2012 was in Common folder. I would like to use some styles that was placed there but i dont find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now find theses styles in this file on your computer :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt\xaml\design\generic.xaml